# Mounting TV to drywall with no "gap" inside the drywall?

Tags: drywall, mounting, fastener

I have an interior wall in my 1970 condo unit which I'm trying to mount a [heavy TV](https://www.lg.com/us/tvs/lg-oled77g1pua-oled-4k-tv) to. I recently had some construction folks round who installed a wooden stud for me in the wall, however they have since gone awol, so I can't get in touch with them for guidance.

My TV comes with a mount, it requires 8 screws to securely fasten to the wall - 4 top and 4 bottom. Across about 16 inches left to right.

The wall previously had metal studs in, the construction guys tore down the wall and installed - from what I can tell - a single wooden stud for me to use as well. This stud is about 8 inches off center. i.e. the TV will be mounted centrally if I attach the mount to this stud with the rightmost screw.

16 inches to the left of the stud is a metal stud. I plan to use a Driller Toggle bolt to secure this side.

Finally, I have 4 more holes to screw into in the middle. My assumption was that this would be a regular hollow piece of drywall to put a drywall anchor into. However upon drilling a pilot hole, I've observed that the wall is not hollow, the drywall/mud continues all the way through to the drywall on the other side of my interior wall.

I've never seen this before, and am not sure of the best way to secure to this wall - should I treat it like a regular stud and simply mount with a screw? Of course, the anchors won't go in and wouldn't be appropriate. What would my options be here?

Comment: Would use a piece of plywood or a couple of boards attached to the wood stud and metal stud.  Attach the TV mount to plywood/boards.  I do not trust drywall anchors for more than a few pounds.

Comment: That's a shame - the TV mount is a "flush mount" i.e. there would be no gap between the TV and the wall. That being said this'll be in 2 studs and whatever is in the middle, no drywall anchor.

Comment: @crip659 - I had some other construction project going on at home, and asked the contractors to open my wall and add studs. Your response is what they ended up doing instead.